# how to retrieve memory type ( rdimm or udimm)?

Tags: memory, powershell, wmi, powershell-2.0

is there a way to know if installed memory is Registered DIMM or Unregistered DIMM ? the [win32_physicalMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't seem to provide this info ?

you can find more info about udimm rdimm [here](http://www.servethehome.com/unbuffered-registered-ecc-memory-difference-ecc-udimms-rdimms/)

EDIT : the solution provided by @C.B doesnt work either
[image]

Comment: I don't have any experience with registered dimm. Is registered memory like memory with ecc (error correction)? If so, check out the wmiclass `Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray`. Read more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394348(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Graimer i've added a link to provide more infos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I didn't find any simple solution, i think I will do it by scraping the dell support site (providing the server ServiceTag on this url) : `http://support.euro.dell.com/support/DPP/Index.aspx?c=fr&cs=RC1077983&l=fr&s=pad&ServiceTag=XXXXXX`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first idea is using WMI `Win32_PhysicalMemory` and test if TotalWidth (bit count including  check bits) is greater than DataWidth (bit count excluding check bits).

```
    gwmi Win32_PhysicalMemory | select totalwidth, datawidth, banklabel | 
 % {
 if ( $_.totalwidth > $_.datawidth )
 {
    "$($_.banklabel) is ECC memory type"
 }
 else
 {
    "$($_.banklabel) is non-ECC Memory Type"
 }
 }
```

I don't know if exist a best way, and this check if memory is ECC or not.

try this for checking buffered/registered or not memory type:

```
$a = Get-WMIObject -Class "Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray"

 Switch ($a.MemoryErrorCorrection) {
                    0 {Write-Host "ECC Type....:  Reserved"}
                    1 {Write-Host "ECC Type....:  Other"}
                    2 {Write-Host "ECC Type....:  Unknown"}
                    3 {Write-Host "ECC Type....:  None"}
                    4 {Write-Host "ECC Type....:  Parity"}
                    5 {Write-Host "ECC Type....:  Single-bit ECC"} #unbuffered
                    6 {Write-Host "ECC Type....:  Multi-bit ECC"}  #registed
                    7 {Write-Host "ECC Type....:  CRC"}
                }
```

Comment: thank you, are you sure this is validating registered type? seems to  only indicate if ECC is present. but you can have udimm ECC ...

Comment: +1 for your suggestion but I need to validate this at work (tomorrow)

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems to only get the characteristic of ECC single/multi bit, not if it use memory registers (have a look at the link at the bottom of my question). But I'm really appreciate your research efforts

Comment: @Kayasax check it tomorrow and let me know,je suis presque sure!

Comment: @Kayasax I'm so sad now... :(

Comment: @CB. I wont discuss powershell here only want to know how accurate this theory is:

if totalwidth greater than datawidth, it must be a ECC RAM ?

if totalwidth equal or less than datawidth, it must be a non ECC RAM?