# Check memory type (ECC or not) by using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, memory

I am trying to check memory types on all PCs across company. My testing code is below [based on info from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882767/how-to-retrieve-memory-type-rdimm-or-udimm):

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory |
    Select-Object -Property PSComputerName, DeviceLocator, Manufacturer, PartNumber, @{label = "Size/GB" ; Expression = {$_.capacity / 1GB}}, Speed, datawidth, totalwidth, @{label = "ECC" ; Expression = {
        if ( $_.totalwidth > $_.datawidth ) {
            "$($_.DeviceLocator) is ECC memory type"
        }
        else {
            "$($_.DeviceLocator) is non-ECC Memory Type"
        }
    }
} | Out-GridView
```

The results showing me that memory type is non-ecc:

[image]

But if I use 3rd party tool like "HWiNFO64 v4.30" the result is ECC memory. See pic below. How can I get the same memory info like pic below by using PowerShell? Speciously "Memory type" "Speed" and "ECC"

[image]

Comment: What happens if you change `$_.totalwidth > $_.datawidth` to `$_.totalwidth -gt $_.datawidth`? And if that does not work `[int]($_.totalwidth) -gt [int]($_.datawidth)`

Comment: Your issues are you need to use the correct comparison operators and cast the integers since you will be doing string comparison otherwise

Comment: I am not sure if WMI data is supposed to be 100% accurate.. I could be mistaken, but I will not expect it to query the data from the actual hardware on it's own.

Comment: i m not sure if this is correct [$_.totalwidth > $_.datawidth] = [Non-ECC RAM]...beside WMI what else can i use for querying ram information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vikas could have some good points about the accuracy of the information which should be considered. The linked post eludes to other issues as well.

The issue you are running into with this code is your use of [PowerShell Comparison Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx).

They are in the format of `-gt` and `-lt` for example which are greater than and less than respectively. Assuming your logic you should just have to update

```
if ( $_.totalwidth > $_.datawidth )
```

to

```
if ( $_.totalwidth -gt $_.datawidth )
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The results from powershell indicates that the type of the memory is 0 which is unknonw, and missing some infomation too.