# How to determine if Memory is ECC or Non-ECC by datawidth and totalwidth?

Tags: memory

I am trying to list type of physical RAM on all servers. I found [script here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882767/how-to-retrieve-memory-type-rdimm-or-udimm) determine the type by datawidth and totalwidth.

```
gwmi Win32_PhysicalMemory | select totalwidth, datawidth, banklabel | 
 % {
 if ( $_.totalwidth -gt $_.datawidth )
 {
    "$($_.banklabel) is ECC memory type"
 }
 else
 {
    "$($_.banklabel) is non-ECC Memory Type"
 }
 }
```

I wont discuss powershell here only want to know how Accurate this theory is:

if totalwidth greater than datawidth, it must be a ECC RAM ?

if totalwidth equal or less than datawidth, it must be a non ECC RAM?

Comment: Why don't you ask the author of that script for their reference (leave a comment). They were active on SO just 3 hours ago.